# How to apply captions to non-floating Listings

Tags: captions, listings, fancyvrb, fvextra

One way to add captions to code listings is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{margin=0.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{codelisting}
\caption{test}
test
\end{codelisting}

\end{document}
```

However, I do *not* want my `codelisting` element to be a float because I want to ensure page breaking for very long listings.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\newenvironment{codelisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{codelisting}
\caption{test}
test
\end{codelisting}

\end{document}
```

But I got an error:

> LaTeX Error: No counter 'listing' defined.

How can I apply captions to non-float elements in LaTeX? specifically listings using the `fancyvrb` and `fvextra` packages?

## Edit

In response to @Skillmon's comment. Pandoc doesn't nest `\label` inside `\caption`, so what I tried is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

\renewenvironment{codelisting}
    {\captionsetup{type=codelisting}}
    {}

\begin{document}

text pre
\begin{codelisting}
\label{test}
\caption{test}
\VerbatimInput[breaknonspaceingroup, breaklines, breakanywhere]{verbatim.py}
\end{codelisting}
text post
AS shown in Listing \ref{test}

\end{document}
```

Which does compile, but the reference is not resolved as the image below shows:

[image]

Comment: why aren't you using `listings`? It has caption support build in floating or not.

Comment: Two reasons: 1) the real world scenario is using Pandoc and `pandoc-crossref`, which uses `fancyvrb` and `fvextra` for its default LaTeX template (I'm trying to customize the template to my needs). 2) Listings has inferior syntax highlighting than Pygments, which is ultimately what Pandoc uses to render code listings.

Comment: What daleif says. If there is a reason to not use it, consider `\captionof` (see `caption`) package.

Comment: @Οὖτις I've already tried `\captionof` and couldn't get it to work. Would you be able to provide a full working example based on my MWE?

Comment: I'd guess your `type=` is wrong, after your `\newfloat`, the `type=` should be `codelisting` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Skillmon I get the error "No counter codelisting defined" if I do that

Comment: Then define the counter (`\newcounter{codelisting}`)

Comment: @daleif I get "no float type codelisting defined" if I define a new counter

Comment: Show your code (in your question) instead of "telling" us what you did.

Comment: @daleif. Sorry, but I have already showed enough code and done the work necessary to boil this down to an MWE. If you believe your suggestions can fix my issue, then you can  try them out yourself on the MWE I have provided and then provide a fleshed out answer, which I would then gladly upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

\newenvironment{code}[2][]
  {\captionof{codelisting}{#2}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\label{#1}\fi}
  {}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{code}{test}
        test
\end{code}
    
foo

\begin{code}[lst:1]{testA} % with label
    test
\end{code}

See Listing~\ref{lst:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok that seems to work. If I include a `\VerbatimInput[breaknonspaceingroup, breaklines, breakanywhere]{verbatim.py}` for a very long Python file I get captions, line and page breaking, Would you please provide a little more background on how you did that? Is there perhaps a way to do it where I can keep a `\label` and `\caption` control sequence inside that `code` environment?

Comment: @user32882 if you take a careful look, this is basically the same as my comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679687/how-to-apply-captions-to-non-floating-listings/679696?noredirect=1#comment1686667_679687 (which you claimed didn't work).

Comment: @Skillmon please provide a fleshed out answer if you think you have a better solution.

Comment: @user32882: define `\newcommand\Caption{\captionof{codelisting}}`  and then you can use `\Caption` (uppercase C)

Comment: @user187802 no, `pandoc-crossref` outputs it as lowercase `\caption` and it's very difficult to change that.

Comment: do you have also other floating environments (like figure, table,...) with a caption in your document?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be unable to do what a comment suggests, here is an answer that does what my comment suggested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

\renewenvironment{codelisting}
  {\captionsetup{type=codelisting}}
  {}

\begin{document}
text pre
\begin{codelisting}
  \caption{test}
  some code
\end{codelisting}
text post
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a version with correct spacing (didn't check whether spacing is correct if you nest `\VerbatimInput` etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{codelisting}
  {%
    \par
    \vspace*{\intextsep}% vertical spacing as a float
    \captionsetup{type=codelisting}%
  }
  {%
    \par
    \vspace*{\intextsep}% vertical spacing as a float
    \@endpetrue % following text is only indented if blank line after \end
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text pre
\begin{codelisting}
  \caption{test\label{code:works}}
  some code
\end{codelisting}
text post \ref{code:works}
\end{document}
```

[image: result with label and ref]

---

Alternative input to get above's output with `\label` not nested inside `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{codelisting}
  {%
    \par
    \vspace*{\intextsep}% vertical spacing as a float
    \captionsetup{type=codelisting}%
  }
  {%
    \par
    \vspace*{\intextsep}% vertical spacing as a float
    \@endpetrue % following text is only indented if blank line after \end
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text pre
\begin{codelisting}
  \caption{test}
  \label{code:works}
  some code
\end{codelisting}
text post \ref{code:works}
\end{document}
```

Output looks identical (but please note that the optimal input syntax is with `\label` nested in the mandatory argument of `\caption` -- there are border cases in which the output might not look identical).

Comment: spacing isn't too important to me, but references are. When using `\label` and `\ref` your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @user32882 I just tried, `\label` and `\ref` work as expected.

Comment: Pandoc doesn't nest `\label` inside `\ref` like that. Please see edit to show why your suggestion doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user32882 that's a syntax error in your edit, `\label` must always be either nested inside `\caption` or follow it. Putting `\label` before `\caption` can not work!