# Rewriting non float code listings Pandoc compatibility

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, pandoc, fancyvrb, fvextra

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679687/how-to-apply-captions-to-non-floating-listings) I asked whether it would be possible to create a listing in LaTeX using `fancyvrb` and `fvextra` satisfying the following requirements:

- Allowing for page breaking (non-float)
- Line breaking
- References, labels and captions

It turns out this can be implemented as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

\newenvironment{code}[2][]
  {\captionof{codelisting}{#2}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\label{#1}\fi}
  {}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{code}{test}
        test
\end{code}
    
foo

\begin{code}[lst:1]{testA} % with label
    test
\end{code}

See Listing~\ref{lst:1}

\end{document}
```

The ability for page breaking and line breaking can be demonstrated by replacing the contents of the `code` environment as follows:

```
\begin{code}[lst:1]{testA}
    \VerbatimInput[breaknonspaceingroup, breaklines, breakanywhere]{verbatim.py}
\end{code}
```

Where `verbatim.py` is some file containing a lot of verbatim code.

What I did *not* mention in that question is that I am adapting Pandoc's default LaTeX template to be able to create such listings using the `pandoc-crossref` filter. This filter only generates listings that look like the following:

```
\begin{codelisting}
    \caption{test}
    \label{test}
    verbatim content
\end{codelisting}
```

Adapting `pandoc-crossref` and Pandoc to do otherwise is quite difficult.

Is there perhaps a way to rewrite the LaTeX code in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679687/how-to-apply-captions-to-non-floating-listings) so that the `\label` and `\caption` macros can be written *within* the environment as opposed to being arguments `codelisting`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\captionsetup{type=...}` to enable features like `\caption` (and `\label`), sub-figures (via subfig or subcaption package) etc.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}

% Re-define 'codelisting' as a non-floating environment
\renewenvironment{codelisting}[1][] % ignore optional positioning parameter
  {\par\vskip\intextsep
   \captionsetup{type=codelisting}%
   \ignorespaces}
  {\par\vskip\intextsep}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{codelisting}
    \caption{test}
    test
\end{codelisting}
    
foo

\begin{codelisting}
    \caption{testA}
    \label{lst:1}
    test
\end{codelisting}

See Listing~\ref{lst:1}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: Your "Edit" example code in [How to apply captions to non-floating Listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679687/how-to-apply-captions-to-non-floating-listings) simply does not work because you put `\label` in front of `\caption`, but `\label` has to follow `\caption` instead. (Unfortunately I don't have the "reputation" yet to make comments on Tex.SX.) See also: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-crossref